# How do I tell jQuery to ignore the empty server response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I have this code:

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",
     url: theRightUrl,
     data: whatToPost,
     logFunction: whatever,
     suppressSuccessLogging: !0,
     dataType: "html"
   });
```

and when the server returns HTTP 204 and empty response Firefox emits "no element found" error. According to [jQuery manual](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) there's `contents` parameter that I could use to enable custom treatment of the response.

I'd be happy to have the response just ignored.

How do I use `contents` parameter to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `contents` will help you, since you don't have a response to parse. As long as you're not doing cross-domain, requests, all you should need is an `error` handler that does nothing.

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",
    url: theRightUrl,
    data: whatToPost,
    logFunction: whatever,
    suppressSuccessLogging: !0,
    dataType: "html",
    error: function() {
        // This is still supported, but deprecated, you should
        // consider using $.Deferred instead
    }
});
```

Even better would be using `$.Deferred` objects

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that helps;

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    204: function() {
      alert( "Sorry no response " );
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Cool, but can I use `contents` to specify a "converter" instead?

Comment: As I know contents are using for specifiying the custom types. I'm not sure about the specifiying converter. It should work for your error I think.